# Could not find default endpoint element .net

Tags: .net

I am getting the error that the contract name could not found, but i have added the contract name in the web.config file and in the `reference.cs` file also the interface is present with the same contract name (`ICAMSAuthorizationService`).

```
<endpoint address="my address" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding" 
                contract="CAMSAuthorizationService.ICAMSAuthorizationService" name="netTcpBinding"/>
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
```

```
ERROR--->PerformanceAnalysis.rblAnalysisModes_SelectedIndexChanged--->10/16/2023 12:24:04 PM
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'CAMSAuthorizationService.ICAMSAuthorizationService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at PerformanceTuningExternalProxyHelper.CAMSAuthorizationService.CAMSAuthorizationServiceClient..ctor() in S:\BuildAgentsN1\N1Agent04\_work\28\s\Main\Source\DBPerformanceAnalysis-Dev\PerformanceTuningExternalProxyHelper\Service References\CAMSAuthorizationService\Reference.cs:line 192
   at PerformanceTuningExternalProxyHelper.ServiceWrapper.CAMSAuthorizationService.GetRolesForUser(String applicationCode, String strLoginUserId) in S:\BuildAgentsN1\N1Agent04\_work\28\s\Main\Source\DBPerformanceAnalysis-Dev\PerformanceTuningExternalProxyHelper\ServiceWrapper\CAMSAuthorizationService.cs:line 17
   at DBPerformanceAnalysis.ASPX.PerformanceAnalysis.GetApplications() in S:\BuildAgentsN1\N1Agent04\_work\28\s\Main\Source\DBPerformanceAnalysis-Dev\DBPerformanceAnalysis\ASPX\PerformanceAnalysis.aspx.cs:line 1798
   at DBPerformanceAnalysis.ASPX.PerformanceAnalysis.rblAnalysisModes_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in S:\BuildAgentsN1\N1Agent04\_work\28\s\Main\Source\DBPerformanceAnalysis-Dev\DBPerformanceAnalysis\ASPX\PerformanceAnalysis.aspx.cs:line 224
```